# Windows 8 phone Stackpanel

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, stackpanel

in my app i would like multiply section grids, these then go done the page one recantgle after another. The problem if i would like to add more sections but they go down below the app design. I have tried to add a stackpanel and stackviewer but neither work. The user should be able to scroll down and see all the sections.

Thank you in advance

The code looks somewhat like this;

```
<Grid Background="Teal">

                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="163" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480">
                </Grid>


                <Grid Height="130" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,164,0,0"> 
                </Grid>


                <Grid Height="140" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,295,0,0">
                </Grid>


                <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="0,435,0,129">
                </Grid>

                <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel2" Margin="0,435,0,129">
                </Grid>

</Grid>
```

- The user should be able to scroll down the page and see all the grids, as one grid is off the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine the `<StackPanel>` with a `<ScrollViewer>` to get the scrollable view, so something like:

```
<Grid Background="Teal">
    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="163" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480">
            ...
            </Grid>
            <Grid Height="130" VerticalAlignment="Top"> 
            ...
            </Grid>
            <Grid Height="140" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            ...
            </Grid>
            <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel">
            ...
            </Grid>
            <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel2">
            ...
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```